# HTML Redirect After Load

Tags: sas

I’m displaying dropdowns in HTML to alter a SAS output.  The values of the dropdowns only affect SAS each time the page loads.  I want to link to a second page and pass the values of the dropdown.  However SAS is unaware of what the values are unless the current page reloads and saves the dropdown values.  So I want to reload the same page when the user clicks a button.  Then redirect the user to a second page.  All of the redirect code I see redirects the user 100% of the time while I only want to redirect the based on a condition.

Comment: How is SAS involved in this?  Is this in a particular SAS tool, or is this produced via `ODS HTML` or similar?

Comment: Why not refresh with a variable passed in the URL? Then, check to see if variable is set in URL, and redirect if variable is present.

Comment: Removing the [tag:html] tag until more clarification comes from OP.  This is not clearly a HTML issue.

Comment: Currently trying a variation of your post to see if it works.

Comment: I’m using a Web URL Portlet in Information Delivery Portal to display SAS nested inside of HTML.  The dropdown buttons are html and the page acts as a webpage.  When the page refreshes the SAS display is refreshed.

Comment: I’m looking at the structure of each button, each button is inside of a form tag which includes a _program box.  E.g. PUT "<input type='hidden' name='_program' value='/Reports/Research Dashboard/Monthly Expense Report' />";  The _program value determines which form is loaded.  If I could change the value of the _program box to vary based on which button is clicked it would solve the issue.

Comment: This should work however it takes me back to the same page as if I hit a submit button.  I think this is an odd SAS thing.  All the documentation for standard HTML states this should work.
PUT "<button onclick=""window.location.href=""https://serverName/"@;
     PUT "SASPortal/Director?_directive="@;
     PUT "STPRun&_action=execute%nrstr(&_program)=/Reports/Research Dashboard/Monthly Expense Report"@;
PUT "%nrstr(&save_REPORT_MONTH=)&save_REPORT_MONTH""""/>View All Reports</button>";

Answer (score 0):

The method I described in my comment would look something like this.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="saveData()">Save</button>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    if ( getQueryVariable("data") == "saved" ) {
        alert("true");
    }
})();

function saveData() {
    var newPage = window.location.href + "?data=saved";
    window.location.replace(newPage);
}

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

Comment: This is either useful or not useful, depending on a lot of information not yet provided in the question.  SAS is a complicated suite of products, and this may be more of a integrated web suite sort of question.

Comment: @Joe since you seem to be very active on the SAS tag, would you advise me to leave or remove this answer?

Comment: It's up to you; it may become an unhelpful answer, or it may become a helpful answer.  Or the OP may never reply...  Most of the time in SAS, you can't really do what you're describing above, but _some_ of the time it is possible to use javascript/etc.  Just depends on what the OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the dropdownlists
onchange='this.form.submit()'
Which made the refresh button not needed.